# Autowiring Optional<object> in Spring 4.1

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I am trying to autowire Optional in a component.
Object is in custom ThreadScope and proxy-mode = INTERFACES.

I think `@Autowired Optional<ObjectType> objectTypeOptional` just ensures that Autowiring is not requried.
Now `objectTypeOptional.isPresnet()` always returns true. Because there is a proxy for ObjectType. Is there a way to say that objectTypeOptional is not present?

**Post Edit (Adding more context to the question):**

My bean is something like this -

```
@Component
public User {
    private final userName;
    private final userEmail;
    // constructors and getters
}
```

Now I want to inject Optional of User in any service or controller. Something like -
`@Autowired Optional<User> userOptional;`

So whenever a user is logged in, a filter/interceptor will create an appropriate `User` object. But when no user is logged in I should be able to check it via optional -
`userOptional.isPresent()`

Answer (score 1):

I believe Provider would be more fit for you.

[Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Provider.html)

You would autowire

```
@Resource
Provider<UsersConnectionRepository> usersConnectionRepositoryProvider;
```

and have a method or call `get()` on the Provider

```
private UsersConnectionRepository getUserConnectionRepository() {
    return usersConnectionRepositoryProvider.get();
  }
```

Also you can do `@Autowired(required = false)`.

Comment: I actually want a way to figure out if the object is present or not. For example I create a `User` object whenever there is logged in user. Otherwise the `User` object is null. So if I can inject `Optional<User>` I can then check if the `User` is present or not before accessing it.

Comment: If you make the user then you can make Optional yourself as well using its  methods `Optional.of(..)` or `Optional.ofNullable(..)`.

Comment: I am sorry. I still didn't understand your solution totally. Are you saying -
`@Autowired Provider<Optional<User>> optionalUserProvider;`
and have a method `get()` on the provider
`private Optional<User> getOptionalUser() {}`

Comment: Not quite. Can you show your bean where you would want to return that?

Comment: Added more context to the question. Please check the Post Edit section.